# How is New Horizon able to send back data to Earth?

Tags: antennas, space-mission, solar-system-exploration

New Horizon is to send back images of Ultima Thule, 6.4 billion kilometres away. 
Barred having a very large power to send information back on a very large angle, it seems to me that the level of precision to send this information back so that it can captured by an antenna on Earth is prohibitively hard to get.
How is NASA accomplishing it?

Comment: This is really an engineering problem, not a physics problem.  And obviously it's not **prohibitively** hard because they are doing it.  We still get info from the Voyagers.

Comment: Of course I know we are doing it, but to me looks prohibitively hard. Should I move the question to another SE site?

Comment: I thought it would be physics since it is all about calculations of orbits, strength of radio waves, etc. I don’t think it warrants being put on hold as off-topic.

Comment: @user I think the key is that you asked how NASA _is_ doing it. If you want to make your question on topic here, it should be more about how they _could be_ doing it, but you should probably edit the question to ask specific questions about the physical principles involved - for example, look up some of the technology involved and then maybe you could ask something about how to figure out how effective it is at amplifying signals. (For the record, [space.se] also handles questions like this.)

Comment: To moderators: not sure why the comment with a link to an article was deleted. Can please be reposted?